# Правильное использование отношений mongoose

Tags: база-данных, node.js, mongoose

Есть две модели: Student и Grade (приведу их код ниже). Я делаю своё API и у меня есть POST запрос `/api/student/find`, который в body получает `id` студента. Я не могу правильно оформить ответ. Мне нужно получить ответ вида

```
"student": {
        "date": "2020-11-12T10:25:02.237Z",
        "visits": [],
        "_id": "5fad0da3cbcbd02a1599a8f7",
        "name": "Владимир Владимирович",
        "grade": {
            "students": [
                "5fad10691a55c62d7ef45fbd"
            ],
            "_id": "5fad0b5e56f75f26c4d7fcbe",
            "title": "5Б",
            "createdAt": "2020-11-12T10:15:58.467Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-12T10:37:29.320Z",
            "__v": 1
        },
        "createdAt": "2020-11-12T10:25:39.949Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-11-12T10:25:39.949Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Я делаю это так:

```
const [student] = await Student.findById(id);

if (!student) {
   return res.json({
        status: 401,
        success: false,
        message: "Профиль не найден"
   });
}
const grade = await Grade.findById(student.grade);
student.grade = grade;
```

Но в документации нашел метод populate и пробую делать так (только почему-то получаю undefined, а если делаю console.log внутри callback'а, то всё отлично):

```
const grade = await Student.findById(id).populate('grade').exec(function (err: any, student: any) {
            return student.grade;
        });
```

Как всё таки правильно работать с отношениями? Если же через populate, то как мне сделать так, чтобы undefined я не получал?

Student:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            maxlength: 40,
            minlength: 1,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date(),
            required: true
        },
        grade: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Grade"
        },
        visits: [{
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Visit"
        }]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
export default Student;
```

Grade:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            maxlength: 10,
            minlength: 1,
            required: true
        },
        teacher: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Teacher"
        },
        students: [{
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Student"
        }],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

const Grade = mongoose.model('Grade', GradeSchema);
export default Grade;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await Student.findById(id)
      .populate("grade")
      .exec(function (err: Error, student: mongosee.Document) {
        if (!student) {
          return res.json({
            status: 401,
            success: false,
            message: "Профиль не найден",
          });
        }

        return res.json({
          status: 200,
          success: true,
          student,
        });
      });
  };
```